# Dispose SmtpClient in SendComplete?

Tags: c#, dispose, smtpclient, sendasync

When I use SmtpClient's SendAsync to send email, how do I dispose the `smtpclient` instance correctly?

Let's say:

```
MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
{
   Body = MailBody.ToString(),
   IsBodyHtml = true,
   From = new MailAddress(FromEmail, FromEmailTitle),
   Subject = MailSubject
};
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(i.Email, ""));
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(SmtpServerAddress);
//Add SendAsyncCallback to SendCompleted
sc.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendAsyncCallback);
//using SmtpClient to make async send (Should I pass sc or mail into SendAsyncCallback?)
sc.SendAsync(mail, sc);
```

In the `SendAsyncCallback` method, should I call `sc.Dispose()`, or `mail.Dispose()`?

I checked MSDN document, one example calls MailMessage.Dispose(), but will this dispose method also dispose the `SmtpClient` instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should dispose both the `MailMessage` and the `SmtpClient` in `SendAsyncCallback`.

Disposing the MailMessage will not dispose the SmtpClient automatically (because you might want to send two messages with the same SmtpClient, and you wouldn't want the client to be disposed as soon as you disposed the first message).

Comment: How are you accessing the `MailMessage` from within `SendAsyncCallback` in order to `Dispose` it? If we make it a global variable (field), we're bound to run into collisions (MVC app in this case).

Comment: I was able to do this by sending the `MailMessage` as the token for the second parameter of `SendAsync()`.

Answer (score 1):

This example: from the MSDN Library documentation only closes the Message so I'm going with that in my implementation:  [SmtpClient.SendAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx)

```
message.Dispose();
```

I was running into this issue referred to in this question where the send was always being cancelled so I'm removing my using {} statement:  [SmtpClient.SendAsync Calls are Automatically Cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316785/smtpclient-sendasync-calls-are-automatically-cancelled)

Okay, I just tried issuing the message.Dispose() and even that was throwing the error saying it couldn't send the email because of the message being disposed.  Possibly because mine is a asp.net mvc app and the example is a console app.  In any case the garbage collector should pick up these options once everything falls out of scope...