# SmtpClient.SendAsync Calls are Automatically Cancelled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, smtp, smtpclient

Whenever I call `smtpClient.SendAsync(...)` from within my ASP.NET MVC application, the asynchronous requests are automatically cancelled, even though `SendAsyncCancel()` is never called.

*Synchronous* `.Send(...)` requests, on the other hand, go through just fine.

My `EmailService` service wrapper handles sending asynchronous email with `SmtpClient` from within my ASP.NET MVC 3 application. A service instance is injected into each MVC controller by StructureMap, which wraps a new `SmtpClient` instance in a `using (...) { }` statement.

Here is my `EmailService.SendAsync` wrapper method for `SmtpClient`:

```
public void SendAsync(EmailMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(_cfg.Host, _cfg.Port)
        {
            EnableSsl = _cfg.EnableSsl,
            Credentials = _credentials
        })
        {
            smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(Email_OnCompleted);

            var mailMessage = new MailMessage(message.From, message.To)
                                {
                                    Subject = message.Subject,
                                    Body = message.Body
                                };

            smtpClient.SendAsync(mailMessage, message);

            _logger.Info(string.Format("Sending async email to {0} with subject [{1}]", message.To, message.Subject));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Async email error: " + ex);
        throw;
    }

}
```

Here is my `Email_OnCompleted` delegate:

```
public void Email_OnCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var mail = (EmailMessage)e.UserState;

    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        _logger.Error(string.Format("Error sending email to {0} with subject [{1}]: {2}", mail.To, mail.Subject, e.Error));
    }
    else if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        _logger.Warn(string.Format("Cancelled email to {0} with subject [{1}].", mail.To, mail.Subject));
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.Info(string.Format("Sent email to {0} with subject [{1}].", mail.To, mail.Subject));
    }
}
```

Why are async emails being cancelled, but synchronous emails go through just fine? Could it be a dispose issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It can definitely be a dispose issue. When you dispose the client it cancels any outstanding async operations.

You should dispose the client in `Email_OnCompleted`.

An SO post on where to dispose: [Dispose SmtpClient in SendComplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660353/dispose-smtpclient-in-sendcomplete)

Comment: Fantastic! I ripped out the using (...) statement and async sending now works perfectly. Thanks, Anders!

Comment: Is it possible that the controller will be disposed of along with _logger before the async send completes, resulting in a null reference exception on the ILogger instance?

Comment: More accurately... "When you dispose the client it cancels any outstanding async operations." = When you dispose of the SmtpClient it cancels any outstanding async operations for the instance of the class.

Comment: really helpful. i was wondering about this error and found this