# How to register outlook com component?

Tags: com, outlook, components

I want to run an application to send email in a virtual machine, the VM didn't install outlook, and we are not permitted.
After app runs, I got an error

```
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  
{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154."
```

I can't find COM component with this CLSID in registry, in other PC has outlook,I find the CLSID in registry, and its assembly is `"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"`.

So, I think I should register the outlook com, but I don't know the name of component,and where to download.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} corresponds to the Outlook.Application COM object. It has absolutely nothing in coming with the outlook.com web site besides the word "Outlook" in the name.

Comment: thanks for your input, "outlook com" in my question do means COM object  but not outlook.com, I just want to know the name of COM object, and where to download it.

Comment: That COM object is installed when you install Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I used to send mail via the .NET class **[SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)** like this: **[Properly disposing resources used by SmtpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128390/properly-disposing-resources-used-by-smtpclient)**.

Here is some [**sample code from msdn**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariya/archive/2006/06/15/633007.aspx). I don't think that is the nicest code or approach, but at least there is no COM object to instantiate that's missing half the time. It should work even with .NET 2.0.

And as to downloading **the Outlook COM interface**. You can't as far as I know. **It is installed when you install Outlook itself**. It is just an interface offered by the Outlook executables to allow "application remote control".

One more sample: [Dispose SmtpClient in SendComplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660353/dispose-smtpclient-in-sendcomplete)